# How to do addition of 2 rows in pandas where the column has mixed datatype?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a DataFrame that looks as follow:

---

```
    0             1                  2
   Time        Blocks Left      Blocks Added
0   NaN         Monday            Tuesday
1   NaN        2020-01-01        2020-01-02
2  01:00:00       44               1420
3  02:00:00       55               1520
4  03:00:00       65               1000
5  04:00:00       75               1110
```

Now, I want to add the rows 2 and 3 for the values in columns of 1 and 2.

So the output should be

```
    0             1                  2
   Time        Blocks Left      Blocks Added
0   NaN         Monday            Tuesday
1   NaN        2020-01-01        2020-01-02
2  01:00:00       44               1420
3  02:00:00       55               1520
4  03:00:00       65               1000
5  04:00:00       75               1110
                  99               2940
```

But since the columns 1 and column 2 contain date in the row-1 hence pandas is detecting the entire column as object datatype, so can someone tell me how to do the addition in this case

Comment: its better if you can provide a code that reproduces the input dataframe since it s a mulltiindex and pretty hard to copy and reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better is working with DataFrame with MultiIndex in columns, not mixing data with metadata:

```
df = df.set_index(0)
t = df.iloc[:3].apply(tuple).tolist()
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(t)
df = df.iloc[3:].astype(int).rename_axis(None)
print (df)
         Blocks Left Blocks Added
              Monday      Tuesday
          2020-01-01   2020-01-02
01:00:00          44         1420
02:00:00          55         1520
03:00:00          65         1000
04:00:00          75         1110
```

If possible, create `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex in columns` in `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=[0], header=[0,1,2])
```

Then you can add new row by [`setting with enlargement`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
df.loc['05:00:00'] = [99, 2940]
print (df)
         Blocks Left Blocks Added
              Monday      Tuesday
          2020-01-01   2020-01-02
01:00:00          44         1420
02:00:00          55         1520
03:00:00          65         1000
04:00:00          75         1110
05:00:00          99         2940
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

You can try this out.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
df.append(df2)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  5  6
1  7  8
```